# How can I get the length of text entered in a textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the length of text entered in a textbox using jQuery?

Comment: @Izzy That's all right, since this question is old enough to bump up in google results. Thereby I present you one of the most well known help vampires of SO.

Comment: And herein lies support for an answer I gave on meta.stackoverflow, which received 39 downvotes before it was deleted by the stack overflow status quo, where I argued that even low quality novice questions accrete value. I am vindicated. They didn't like my answer because it grated against the egos of the high-rep incumbent members who think StackOverflow is all about them.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

```
var myLength = $("#myTextbox").val().length;
```

Answer (score 108):

If your textbox has an id attribute of "mytextbox", then you can get the length like this:

```
var myLength = $("#mytextbox").val().length;
```

- `$("#mytextbox")` finds the textbox by its id.
- `.val()` gets the value of the input element entered by the user, which is a string.
- `.length` gets the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Up Vote because you explained what it all does, not jsut provided the code.

Comment: If your text field doesn't have an id, you can reference it by name. Do a `$("input[name='myinputname']").val().length;`

Answer (score 10):

For me its not text box its a span tag and this worked for me.

```
var len = $("span").text().length;
```

Answer (score 5):

Below mentioned code works perfectly fine for taking length of any characters entered in textbox.

`$("#Texboxid").val().length;`

Answer (score 2):

### **CODE**

```
$('#montant-total-prevu').on("change", function() {

var taille = $('#montant-total-prevu').val().length;

    if (taille > 9) {

//TODO

}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to only grab the element with an appropriate jQuery selector and then the `.val()` method to get the string contained in the input textbox and then call the `.length` on that string.

`$('input:text').val().length`

However, be warned that if the selector matches multiple inputs, `.val()` will only return the value of the **first** textbox. You can also change the selector to get a more specific element but keep the `:text` to ensure it's an input textbox.

On another note, to get the length of a string contained in another, non-input element, you can use the `.text()` function to get the string and *then* use `.length` on *that* string to find its length.

Comment: -1 You're wrong, it only returns the length of the **very first** input box's value. http://jsfiddle.net/8Khzf/

Comment: Thanks alot. Its helpful. I learn new way to check input type. before seeing your answer i was used to $("input[type='text']").