# Shrink a text if more than 10 characters length

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have the Following `<h2>` "Example example example example". I want to detect the lenght of this `<h2>` and if it's more than 10 characters, shrink it to "Example ex...". Get it? Shrink it to 10 characters long and add "..." to the end.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<h2>Example example example example example</h2>
<h2>Example</h2>
```

jQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dtl = $('.h2').text().length;

        if(dtl>10){
        $('.h2').text().length = 10;
        $('.h2').text($('.h2').text()+"...");
    } 
});
```

But that's not working...

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but if people don't like this question my guess is it's because you're basically asking other people to write your code for you.

Comment: what? I posted code and I tried, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815146/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-text-entered-in-a-textbox-using-jquery, and it has like 90+ upvotes? Someone hates me here and downvotes all of my posts..

Comment: You want to truncate the text when it's *less* than 10 characters? That sounds counter-intuitive.

Comment: I've detected the lenght and tried to shrink it but it didn't work so I posted my question here. The detection part works great but the other one does not. Isn't this site all about asking programming questions?

Comment: Yes, programming questions are welcome. My point is that I think you mean "if it's *more* than 10 characters", not less. The way it's currently written is confusifying.

Comment: Ahh sorry I'll correct it, english is not my native language :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use substr in this case:

And you have `h2` tag elements and not `.h2` classname.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dtl = $("h2").text().length;

     if(dtl>10){
        $('h2').text($('h2').text().substr(0,10)+"...");
    } 
});
```

Am doing just for one element, you may need to use `$("h2").each()` to target all the elements.

More complete code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

         $("h2").each(function() {
             if($(this).text().length > 10) {
               $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,10)+"...");
             }
         });
    });
```

**DEMO**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $("h2").each(function() {
         if($(this).text().length > 10) {
           $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,10)+"...");
         }
     });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example example example example example</h2>
<h2>Example</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `<h2>` tags you will have to use

```
$("h2").each(function() {
   var dtl = $(this).text().length;
   //rest of your code goes here
   if(dtl>10){
      var res = $(this).text();
      res = res.substring(0, 4); //apply your logic here what ever you want pass (0, 10)
     $(this).text(res +"...");
   } 
});
```

Comment: ".. and if it's less than 10 characters, shrink it to .." Although I believe that's just poor wording and not the real intention :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,it may works

```
<h2>This tag contains more than 10 characters</h2>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var len = $("h2").text().length;
        var text = $("h2").text();

        if (len > 10) {
            var stext = text.substring(0, 10);
            $("h2").text(stext).append("...");
        }

    });
```